# `login` from X session

Tags: linux, fedora, login, gui

I seem to remember it used to be possible to `login` via a GUI terminal.  This was useful if (e.g.) you added yourself to a new group and want to use those privileges without stopping X to log in normally (since acquiring the new group requires a login).<sup>1</sup>  You can, of course, switch to a different VT, but this can be a hassle particularly if what you want to do requires an X display.

But on my current Fedora 20 w/ kernel 3.11, `login` just hangs indefinitely.  In the system logs:

```
login: FATAL: /dev/pts/3: change permissions failed: Operation not permitted
```

How can I get around this?

---

<sup>1. As it turns out you can get around all that by via `su youself`, which performs a login...</sup>

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the whole thing, but would a 'newgrp <group>' have sufficed?

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the ideal solution, but it will work.

First, to get around the permissions issue, `su root`.  Next `exec login` -- the reason for this is at the end of `man login`:

> A  recursive login, as used to be possible in the good old days, no longer works; for most purposes su(1) is a satisfactory substitute.    Indeed, for security reasons, login does a vhangup() system call to remove any possible listening processes on the  tty.   This  is  to      avoid password sniffing.  If one uses the command login, then the surrounding shell gets killed by vhangup() because it's no longer the      true owner of the tty.  **This can be avoided by using exec login in a top-level shell or xterm.**

You may then get hung by:

```
Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session
```

This will be reflected in the system logs along with:

```
login: pam_loginuid(login:session): set_loginuid failed
```

Probably also related to the recursion and that your `uid` doesn't match your user name: `session opened for user golidlocks by golilocks(uid=0)` (because `goldilocks`'s uid in the `su` session was set to 0).

You can get around that by commenting out the following line *temporarily* in `/etc/pam.d/login`:

```
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
```

Note that in order to access the GUI, you will probably have to use a `--display` (e.g., `--display :0`) argument to your app, as you would from a VT console.

Comment: +1 but why not just do `su - user`? Or even `bash -l`? Or will that not update the groups?

Comment: @terdon : `bash -l` doesn't but low and behold, `su` does.  Guess I should have tried that, lol, or at least deduced it later based on the fact that pam logs su sessions...well, maybe this will still serve some purpose for someone, somewhere...some day... An advantage of the `su` method is you don't need to use `--display`.

Comment: Heh, and I guess you spent about an hour figuring all this out :). Weird though, `bash -l` starts a login shell on my system (at least, it sources `~/.profile` and not `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: @terdon : I guess that's what the relevance of "login" is to bash, so processing `/etc/passwd` isn't part of it.  If you watch where ever your `auth` stuff gets logged, `bash -l` doesn't do anything.  It wasn't quite an hour, lol...best part is the reason was so I could use wireshark to debug an `sshfs` problem that was caused by *a typo*.